# how to loop through secondary set of data if not found in first set?

Tags: python-3.x

How to iterating through second set of data if nothing found in first set of data?

## data that is being looped

```
In [113]: bpimage_cmd_split
Out[113]:
['Client:            hostname',
 'Backup ID:         hostname_1555238197',
 'Policy:            Policy1',
 'Proxy Client:      (none specified)',
 'Job ID:            4630451',
 'Data_Classification_ID: (none specified)',
 'Storage Lifecycle Policy:    SLP-DATA-Infinite',
 'Origin Master GUID:    (none specified)',
 ' ID:               @aaaaC',
 ' ID:               @aaaaE',
 ' ID:               L02551',]

In [151]: type(bpimage_cmd_split)
Out[151]: list
```

## snippet of code

```
last_backup_image = sorted(id_dict.values())[-1]
second_backup_image = sorted(id_dict.values())[-2]
bpimage_cmd = ssh_connect.run(rf"sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpimagelist -L -backupid {last_backup_image} -media | egrep -e 'Policy:' -e 'ID:' -e 'Client:'")
backup_client_info = {}

bpimage_cmd_split = [bpimage_name.strip() for bpimage_name in cbpimage_cmd.stdout.split('\n') if bpimage_name.strip()]

for item in bpimage_cmd_split:
    if len(item.strip()) == 0:
        continue

    data_split = [s.strip() for s in item.split(':')]

    if data_split[0] == 'ID':
        if not '@aaa' in data_split[1]:
            if data_split[0] not in backup_client_info:
                backup_client_info[data_split[0]] = [data_split[1]]
            else:
                backup_client_info[data_split[0]].append(data_split[1])    
    else:
        backup_client_info[data_split[0]] = data_split[1]
```

the code works as expected.

But through some more QA testing, it's possible that the data from, last_backup_image, bpimage_cmd_split has "ID:" as all @aaaa because the backup job is still running? If this is the case, then i would like it to loop through "second_backup_image" and get IDs not containing @aaa?

Comment: The last part of your question is not clear. Please rephrase!

Comment: Can you show an example of the data that causes the problem, and what you want to do with it?

Comment: Your last line makes `backup_client_info[data_split[0]]` a string. The rest of the code expects it to be a list. Shouldn't it also use `= [data_split[1]]`?

Comment: It seems like you just need an `if` statement that tests the condition you're talking about, and then performs all the same code using `second_backup_image`. Maybe move most of this code into a function that takes the backup ID as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar,I did it with another if state like: if "ID" not in backup_client_info: bpimage_cmd = ssh_connect.run(rf"sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpimagelist -L -backupid {second_backup_image} -media | egrep -e 'Policy:' -e 'ID:' -e 'Client:'") and then go through the scode. Moving it to a function would be the ideal way to do it, but I'm newbie to python and the script as a whole was a challenge to negin with. I would need to wrap my head around functions before revamping it. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "ID" not in backup_client_info: 
    bpimage_cmd = ssh_connect.run(rf"sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bpimagelist -L -backupid {second_backup_image} -media | egrep -e 'Policy:' -e 'ID:' -e 'Client:'")
```

Comment: How does this work? If all the ID lines have `@aaaa`, the `else:` block still does `backup_client_info[data_split[0]] = data_split[1]`

Comment: if ID only have @aaa, backup_client_info will not have any "ID" keys like in below ouput. if "ID" not in backup_client_info: is outside to check second image afterwards. will see how/if i can show you the whole code if you like? 'code' In [93]: bpimage_cmd_split
Out[93]:
['Client:            hostname',
 'Backup ID:         hostname_1552104188',
 'Policy:            Policy1',
 'Proxy Client:      (none specified)',
 'Job ID:            4086022',
 'Data_Classification_ID: (none specified)',
 'Storage Lifecycle Policy:    SLP-DATA-Infinite',
 'Origin Master GUID:    (none specified)',]

Comment: is the last `else:` supposed to go with `if data_split[0] == 'ID':` instead of `if not '@aaa' in data_split[1]:`?

Comment: Your original code snippet had indentation and wrapping all messed up. I tried to clean it up, maybe I got it wrong.

Comment: apologies for the messed up code, im new to the site but see why its important. the last else: go with if not '@aaa' in data_split[1]

Comment: yeah, i already fixed that in the question. Now this answer makes more sense.